# Querying XML in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table MyTable with three fields - FIELD1 , FIELD2 and FIELD3. I receive XML as below. Can we convert this xml into tabular form using SQL query. [I know we can convert the xml where tag names are field_name and tag value is field value, but here the xml format is different. Here field name is the tag value for tag  and field value is the value for tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
   <parameters>
      <parameter>
         <key>Field1</key>
         <value>Field1_value</value>      
      </parameter> 
      <parameter>
         <key>Field2</key>
         <value>Field2_value</value>      
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
         <key>Field3</key>
         <value>Field3_value</value>      
      </parameter>
   <parameters> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XMLQuery or XMLTable with an Xpath that picks the parameters and filters for each key value:

```
select *
from xmltable ('/body/parameters'
  passing <your XML document>
  columns field1 varchar2(20) path 'parameter[key="Field1"]/value',
          field2 varchar2(20) path 'parameter[key="Field2"]/value',
          field3 varchar2(20) path 'parameter[key="Field3"]/value'
);
```

Demo with the XML (with fixed closing tag!) passed in as a string literal via an XMLType constructor call:

```
select *
from xmltable ('/body/parameters'
  passing xmltype('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
   <parameters>
      <parameter>
         <key>Field1</key>
         <value>Field1_value</value>      
      </parameter> 
      <parameter>
         <key>Field2</key>
         <value>Field2_value</value>      
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
         <key>Field3</key>
         <value>Field3_value</value>      
      </parameter>
   </parameters> 
</body>')
  columns field1 varchar2(20) path 'parameter[key="Field1"]/value',
          field2 varchar2(20) path 'parameter[key="Field2"]/value',
          field3 varchar2(20) path 'parameter[key="Field3"]/value'
);

FIELD1               FIELD2               FIELD3              
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Field1_value         Field2_value         Field3_value
```